# Identifying the sources of mysterious IO that prevent ZFS disks from spinning down

Tags: debian, power-management, zfs, hdparm

I have a Debian system with an SSD as the primary drive and two spinning disks for bulk storage configured with a single mirrored vdev (and a single partition within it).

Those disks are loud, so I'd like them to spin down when they're not in use. However I can't get that to happen when the zfs partition mounted, and I haven't been able to figure out what IO is causing the problem or how to stop it (they do spin down in accordance with the `hdparm -S` setting when not mounted)

I have set `hdparm -s1 -S1 -B10` on both disks, and then tried to find the source of the io with `dstat`. I've confirmed with `fuser -m` that no (persistent) processes are using the mounted zfs partition, and see output like this from `dstat -D sda,sdb,nvme0n1 -cdngy --top-bio-adv --top-io-adv`:

```
--total-cpu-usage-- --dsk/sda-----dsk/sdb---dsk/nvme0n1 -net/total- ---paging-- ---system-- ----most-expensive-block-i/o-process---- -------most-expensive-i/o-process-------
usr sys idl wai stl| read  writ: read  writ: read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw |process              pid  read write cpu|process              pid  read write cpu
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 906  2097 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 895  2082 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0    12k|  60B    0 |   0     0 | 858  2001 |jbd2/dm-1-8        454     0 4096B  0%|awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 838  2028 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 | 771  2010 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0  8192B|2359B  306B|   0     0 | 922  2039 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 420B    0 |   0     0 |1034  2249 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1396B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0   148k|   0     0 |   0     0 |1155  2489 |jbd2/dm-1-8        454     0   48k  0%|awesome            2762  119k1380B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |1275  2858 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1444B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 131B    0 |   0     0 |1032  2315 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1364B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0  8192B|  60B    0 |   0     0 |1147  2362 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1396B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 120B    0 |   0     0 | 969  2071 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  0   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 917  2016 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  0   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 966  2008 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 834  2013 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0   212k|   0     0 |   0     0 | 940  2037 |jbd2/dm-1-8        454     0   16k  0%|awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 |1188  2181 |systemd-journal    510     0  104k  0%|systemd            2532   49M 652B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 790  1888 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 | 916  2065 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 954  2158 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1364B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0    20k|   0     0 |   0     0 |1183  2499 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1444B  0%
  2   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |1221  2346 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867   11k 136k0.2%
  0   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0    40k|  74B  102B|   0     0 | 914  2070 |jbd2/dm-1-8        454     0   32k  0%|awesome            2762  119k1348B0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 393B  330B|   0     0 | 895  2104 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 | 904  2119 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 |1345  2775 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 | 981  2264 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0    32k| 120B   70B|   0     0 |1054  2334 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  2   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :  32k   64k|   0     0 |  32k    0 |1351  2647 |systemd-journal    510     0  108k  0%|tracker-store      1753268  24M 543B1.2%
  5   0  94   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 148B  164B|   0     0 |1450  2948 |                                        |tracker-miner-f    2557   39M  56B4.2%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 |1216  2502 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1396B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :  60k   28k| 283B   94B|   0     0 |1564  3052 |systemd-journal    510    60k 136k  0%|awesome            2762  119k1492B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|1536B    0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |1570  3417 |systemd-journal    510     0   76k  0%|bash               1750409 150k3968B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 933  2090 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k  28k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0    44k|3520B    0 |   0     0 |1100  2283 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1396B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 | 976  2129 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1364B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0    24k|  60B    0 |   0     0 |1009  2120 |jbd2/dm-1-8        454     0   16k  0%|awesome            2762  119k1364B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 120B    0 |   0     0 | 923  1967 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  0   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 | 936  1981 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 | 939  1987 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 871  1969 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0    16k|   0     0 |   0     0 | 888  1989 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 914  2115 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 821  1992 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 848  1991 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 | 806  1957 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  0   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 192B  130B|   0     0 | 792  1976 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0   288k|   0     0 |   0     0 | 847  2077 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 895  2005 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  0   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 829  1966 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 838  2005 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0  4096B|  60B    0 |   0     0 | 880  2050 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 | 890  1982 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0    16k|   0     0 |   0     0 | 856  2008 |jbd2/dm-1-8        454     0 8192B  0%|awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |2017B    0 |   0     0 | 965  2108 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 466B    0 |   0     0 | 806  2019 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 886  1971 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |3051B    0 |   0     0 | 797  2005 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  0   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0  8192B|   0     0 |   0     0 | 818  1931 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |2884B    0 |   0     0 | 978  2154 |systemd-journal    510     0  100k  0%|systemd            2532   49M 612B  0%
  0   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 152B    0 |   0     0 | 815  1965 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0  8192B|   0     0 |   0     0 | 873  2044 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1380B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0   132k|2401B    0 |   0     0 | 985  2221 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 902  2177 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |1205B    0 |   0     0 | 935  2172 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  0   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0    40k|  60B    0 |   0     0 | 909  2014 |jbd2/dm-1-8        454     0   32k  0%|awesome            2762  119k1364B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |1815B    0 |   0     0 | 893  2089 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 | 855  2001 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 794  1969 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  71B    0 |   0     0 | 811  1952 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0    32k|   0   306B|   0     0 | 927  2233 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1380B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B  306B|   0     0 | 865  2225 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0    12k|  46B    0 |   0     0 | 994  2257 |jbd2/dm-1-8        454     0 4096B  0%|awesome            2762  119k1348B0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 430B  306B|   0     0 | 910  2170 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  42B    0 |   0     0 |1011  2179 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 178B    0 |   0     0 |1015  2161 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 |1008  2188 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
--total-cpu-usage-- --dsk/sda-----dsk/sdb---dsk/nvme0n1 -net/total- ---paging-- ---system-- ----most-expensive-block-i/o-process---- -------most-expensive-i/o-process-------
usr sys idl wai stl| read  writ: read  writ: read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw |process              pid  read write cpu|process              pid  read write cpu
  0   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0  4096B|   0     0 |   0     0 | 978  2200 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0   306B|   0     0 | 863  2083 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 794  1956 |                                        |awesome            2762  119k1348B  0%
...
```

one might see several pages with no io on sda and sdb, then something like:

```
--total-cpu-usage-- --dsk/sda-----dsk/sdb---dsk/nvme0n1 -net/total- ---paging-- ---system-- ----most-expensive-block-i/o-process---- -------most-expensive-i/o-process-------
usr sys idl wai stl| read  writ: read  writ: read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw |process              pid  read write cpu|process              pid  read write cpu
  2   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 220B    0 |   0     0 | 918  2132 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  493B 293k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |1042  2148 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867 1326B 238k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B  376B|   0     0 | 905  2130 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  876B 217k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 408B  306B|   0     0 | 846  2066 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  468B 211k  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 918  2039 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  468B 213k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0   306B|   0     0 |1089  2102 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 213k  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 102B    0 |   0     0 | 938  2069 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 210k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 927  2040 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 213k0.1%
  2   0  98   0   0|1536B    0 :1536B    0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 957  2104 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 212k0.2%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  46B  306B|   0     0 | 892  2120 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  468B 211k  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 872  2056 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  468B 212k0.1%
  2   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 904  2051 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 210k  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 921  2067 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 210k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 357B    0 |   0     0 | 917  2071 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 211k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 194B    0 |   0     0 | 922  2037 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 209k  0%
  2   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 915  2088 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 211k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  46B    0 |   0     0 | 853  2044 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 210k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0   306B|   0     0 | 973  2078 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 208k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 920  2086 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 210k  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  42B    0 |   0     0 | 830  2072 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 209k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 426B    0 |   0     0 | 922  2068 |gnome-terminal-    2867    0   12k0.1%|gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 216k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 476B    0 |   0     0 | 897  2110 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  509B 210k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 472B    0 |   0     0 | 887  2116 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  469B 207k0.2%
  2   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 709B    0 |   0     0 | 918  2091 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 208k  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 994  2100 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 208k0.1%
  2   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0    16k|   0     0 |   0     0 | 969  2103 |jbd2/dm-1-8        454     0 8192B  0%|gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 206k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 951  2067 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  509B 209k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 973  2103 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  462B 208k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 990  2042 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 206k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 148B  164B|   0     0 | 941  2083 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 208k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0  8192B|   0     0 |   0     0 | 986  2148 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  468B 208k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 919  2059 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 206k  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 829  2065 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 208k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B  306B|   0     0 | 899  2083 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 206k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B   70B|   0     0 | 998  2057 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  468B 206k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |1486B    0 |   0     0 | 963  2058 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  468B 207k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 964  2093 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 205k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 240B   86B|   0     0 | 943  2058 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 206k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |3258B    0 |   0     0 | 984  2097 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  468B 207k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |2407B    0 |   0     0 | 958  2119 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 204k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 849  2074 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 206k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 925  2073 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 206k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 949  2029 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 204k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 294B    0 |   0     0 | 909  1946 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 206k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  46B    0 |   0     0 | 984  2035 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 204k0.1%
  2   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 920  2087 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 206k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |1033  2403 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 206k  0%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  42B    0 |   0     0 | 763  2024 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 203k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  46B    0 |   0     0 | 985  2093 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 205k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 163B    0 |   0     0 |1015  2097 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 205k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0    12k|   0     0 |   0     0 | 887  2032 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 203k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |1690B    0 |   0     0 | 911  2136 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 205k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |3243B    0 |   0     0 | 876  2098 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 205k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 905  2061 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 203k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 154B    0 |   0     0 | 878  2115 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 205k  0%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 134B  102B|   0     0 | 870  2030 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 203k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0    24k| 353B  102B|   0     0 | 839  1974 |jbd2/dm-1-8        454     0   16k  0%|gnome-terminal-    2867  468B 203k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0   102B|   0     0 | 969  2096 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  523B 207k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  74B  102B|   0     0 | 950  2100 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  469B 204k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 | 944  2103 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  468B 206k  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 134B  274B|   0     0 | 918  2122 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 206k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0    16k| 233B  204B|   0     0 | 888  2084 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  468B 205k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 213B  126B|   0     0 | 953  2079 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  475B 207k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 408B    0 |   0     0 |1030  2058 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  468B 207k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  42B    0 |   0     0 | 953  2097 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 205k  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  42B  102B|   0     0 | 781  1968 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 207k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 737B  130B|   0     0 | 931  2086 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  468B 206k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0   306B|   0     0 | 883  2043 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  468B 208k  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |1928B    0 |   0     0 | 891  2096 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 208k0.1%
  1   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 990  2065 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 206k0.2%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 990  2058 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 207k0.1%
  2   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 901  2063 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 208k  0%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 982  2107 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 205k0.1%
  2   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 | 160B  102B|   0     0 |1005  2081 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 207k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |  60B    0 |   0     0 | 812  2074 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  468B 208k0.1%
  2   0  98   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 999  2050 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  461B 205k0.1%
  1   0  99   0   0|   0     0 :   0     0 :   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 918  2070 |                                        |gnome-terminal-    2867  454B 207k0.1%
```

This table seems to show a tiny amount of read IO on the zfs disk, but not frequently enough to beat the 5 second spindown window, and for some reason isn't reporting the process that's responsible...

Comment: Did you first ensure that your disks support the hdparm's -B & -s options ?

Comment: Yes, I believe they do: https://paste.debian.net/hidden/27c755dc/

Comment: (In the case of `-S`, I see the drives spin down on the specified timeframe if they're not mounted)

Comment: A little more information from `btrace`: https://paste.debian.net/1230811/ shows that `pool-udisksd` seems to be causing some IO on a 10 minute timer. But that's a much longer timescale than the reads shown by `dstat` or the 10 second suspend time.

Comment: You may check with `lsof /poolname` if there are any files in use

Comment: @mashuptwice I did; there weren't.

Comment: You could mount them via systemd, it allows unmounting after a specific time and will mount it as soon as the device gets accessed

Comment: @mashuptwice that sounds like a good plan for resolving the practical issue, though it doesn't entirely answer the investigative question of why this is happening. I will give it a try though!

Answer (score 1):

What I think seemed to do the trick (though there may have been confounding variables) was turning on the "Runtime PM" settings within `powertop` for these two drives. Surprising that that's different than the settings `hdparm` offers.

Comment: I had the same problem with a ZFS setup on Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS, it was constant clicking (in my case 3 disks, and it's right near me...) I couldn't stop the logging urges of jdb2 no matter what I did. I think this Runtime PM setting solved it for me too (I already had powertop and didn't fiddle around with hdparm), though I did enable all the other options there too (they seemed fine to turn to "Good"). The jdb2 is still logging but the disks aren't trying to turn off and on all the time. Nice Q&A, thanks :)